# unable to copy lib files to web-inf/lib

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I'm trying to generate a simple webservice but unable to copy the lib files to web-inf\lib folder.

I don't have great expertise writing ANT scripts but the lib files are not getting copied to the web-inf\lib folder.

Question -
1. How do I modify the ANT script to copy the lib folder to the web-inf folder.
2. Is there any setting in Eclipse that will automatically copy to the web-inf/lib folder.

Here is my project structure -

[image]

ANT Script

```
<project name="WebServices"  basedir=".">
    <description>
        Web Services build file
    </description>
  <!-- set global properties for this build -->
  <property name="src" location="src"/>
  <property name="build" location="build"/>
  <property name="dist"  location="dist"/>
  <property name="webcontent"  location="WebContent"/>

  <target name="init">
        <!-- Create the time stamp -->
        <tstamp/>
        <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
        <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${dist}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="init"
    description="compile the source " >
        <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
        <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="war" depends="compile"
    description="generate the distribution war" >

    <!-- Create the war distribution directory -->
    <mkdir dir="${dist}/war"/>

    <!-- Follow standard WAR structure 
    <copydir dest="${dist}/war/build/WEB-INF/" src="${webcontent}/WEB-INF/" />
    <copydir dest="${dist}/war/build/WEB-INF/classes/" src="${build}" />
    -->
    <copy todir="${dist}/war/build/WEB-INF/" >
        <fileset dir="${webcontent}/WEB-INF/" />
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${dist}/war/build/WEB-INF/classes/" >
        <fileset dir="${build}" />
    </copy>

    <jar jarfile="${dist}/war/HelloWorld-${DSTAMP}.war" basedir="${dist}/war/build/"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

Comment: Why don't you put this jars into the lib folder in the first place?

Comment: How do I add to the lib folder..When I try to copy from the "Libraries" folder to the WEB-INF/lib folder it does not allow me to COPY...

Comment: So maybe try from C:\jars\ folder.